# What does the @ (at) symbol before a filename mean in a curl command?

Tags: shell, curl

I am looking at an [example of a `curl` command](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV#Example) that uses the @ symbol before the filename to post data to the server.

```
curl http://localhost/ --data-binary @file.txt
```

What does this mean? Does it insert the contents of the file into the command? Is it specific to `curl`?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It is specific to curl. From `man curl`:

```
--data-binary <data>
  (HTTP) This posts data exactly as specified with no extra processing whatsoever.
  If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a filename.  Data is
  posted in a similar manner as --data-ascii does, except that newlines are preserved
  and conversions are never done.

  If this option is used several times, the ones following the first will append data
  as described in -d, --data.
```

Comment: I should have looked there. I was expecting it to be a shell thing though. Thanks a million.

Comment: If you came here to learn about the `@`: it has multiple uses. Not just for `--data-binary`. Check the man-page.